# Wait for async to finish when calling getter method?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

i have a model that has a method setImgURL, when a user call this method it saves the image url and call an async task to load the image from URL and save it as bitmap image

```
public void setImgURL(String imgURL) {
    this.imgURL = imgURL;
    LoadImgFromURL().execute(getImgURL());
}

private AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> LoadImgFromURL(){
    return new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
              Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"Loading image");
              String urldisplay = urls[0];

              try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
              setBitmap(result);
      }
    };
}
```

i have another getBitmap method that simply return the bitmap image

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return bmImage;
}
```

is it possible when a user call getBitmap it should wait until the async task completes????

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible :-)

An AsyncTask has a method called get() - if you first execute you task, and then somewhere needed, call the method get() on you AsyncTask object, then your application will wait for the task to finish, and resive the return type.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i tried this but not working...
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    async.get();    
    return bmImage;
}